# boost bind to a class member function passed to QtConcurrent

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am trying to use boost to pass a function to QtConcurrent.

```
QFutureWatcher<GDALDataset> watcher;
QFuture<GDALDataset> future;
GDALDriver *poNITFDriver;

future = QtConcurrent::run(boost::bind(
    &GDALDriver::CreateCopy,
    poNITFDriver,
    pszDstFilename,
    poDataset,
    FALSE,
    papszOptions,
    pfnProgress,
    NULL
));
watcher.setFuture(future);
```

where poNITFDriver is the instance of the class containing the method.

What am I doing wrong here? I get the following compile errors:

> error: no match for `operator=` in future = `QtConcurrent::run(FunctionObject)` with `FunctionObject` = `boost::_bi::bind_t<GDALDataset*, boost::_mfi::mf6<GDALDataset*, GDALDriver, const char*, GDALDataset*, int, char**, int (*)(double, const char*, void*), void*>, boost::_bi::list7<boost::_bi::value<GDALDriver*>, boost::_bi::value<const char*>, boost::_bi::value<GDALDataset*>, boost::_bi::value<bool>, boost::_bi::value<char**>, boost::_bi::value<int (*)(double, const char*, void*)>, boost::_bi::value<long int> > >`

Comment: I'm not certain if `boost::bind` will work as expected with `NULL` as an argument -- `bind` takes arguments of any type and `NULL` is defined to `0`, so the `0` will never be promoted to a pointer type and instead be interpreted as an `int`.

Comment: I added a real argument there, which is a char *, and I am now getting a different error.